# Flying from Cape Town to England and return to another province

Tags: air-travel, england, open-jaw

I am planning a trip to England to visit my family and will be flying from Cape Town.

I wish to fly from Cape Town to England and then return from England to Durban, but I do not wish to purchase 2 one-way tickets as this is a lot more expensive than a return ticket.

Does anyone know if it is at all possible to do this at lower price than 2 one-way tickets?

Answer (score 13):

The intinerary you want is called an **"open-jaw"** ticket. Most airlines offer them at prices similar to return tickets, but they are not always easy to find in the airline's own booking website. You may need to click special options for "advanced search" or "multiple cities".

If everything else fails, go to a brick-and-mortar travel agent, which ought to have no problems issuing an open-jaw ticket (but will probably charge a minor fee for the service).

Comment: I always thought "open-jaw" referred specifically to an itinerary consisting of a flight from A to B and then C back to A.  The OP wants to go from A to B and then from B to C.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: It can be in either direction. One can even have a "double open jaw" A to B then C to D. Airlines use various ways to demand the B is reasonably close to C and A is close to D.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert So did I, but apparently (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-jaw_ticket) this is called **Origin open-jaw** as opposed to the more usual **Destination open-jaw**. I don't  think the name is particularly helpful because I've never seen that term used on a book site, but it's not wrong and the rest of the information is provided.

Comment: For example, [here's a picture of searching for a double open-jaw on Google Flights](https://imgur.com/68dF45d).

Answer (score 5):

In other words to Henning's answer, you will find this option as a Multi-City search on most sites.

Simply, add origin and destination for each leg, and you will get flights in a single itinerary.